# Unable to pass a reference of 'this' to a constructor of another class

Tags: c++, object, reference

We have a `class CJ` that upon it's creation, it creates a different `class BA` object to which it wants to pass a reference to itself like so:

```
BA:BA(const CJ& myCJRef);
```

The compiler always errors with:

> error: uninitialized reference member BA::myCJRef

`CJRef` is defined in the `BA` class as class type `CJ`

Now amounts of `&`, `*` or neither does anything but cause the same error. Initializing is tough since the initialization of `myCJRef` requires passing two other classes but the it would point to the wrong object.

I'm a 'C' guy... this is confounding.

Thanks all!

---

Following the below answers I got to the point where I used this pointer to call methods in the CJ object, the real code follows:

InputPoolBufferAdapter::InputPoolBufferAdapter (CJpsMixerChannel& _CJ, int jitter, int maxBuffers, unsigned long maxBufferAge): myCJpsMixerChannel (_CJ)

```
{
        myCJpsMixerChannel = _CJ;

        myJitter = jitter;  // assuming jitter will be the number of floats

        myJitterCounter = 0;

        myMaxBuffers = maxBuffers;

        myMaxBufferAge = maxBufferAge;

        myPopulateMetadataRequests = 0;

        mySendDataReadyAlert = true;

        clearBufferAdapterThreshhold = CLEAR_BUFFER_ADAPTER_THRESHHOLD;
};    

void InputPoolBufferAdapter::returnDataBufferToPool (ChannelBuffer_t buf) 
{
    void CJpsMixerChannel::myCJpsMixerChannel->returnBufferToInputPool(ChannelBuffer_t *returnBuffer_p);
};

void InputPoolBufferAdapter::notifyDataAvailable ()
{
    void myCJpsMixerChannel.notifyDestinationsDataAvailable(void);
};

void InputPoolBufferAdapter::bufferAdapterError (int a)
{
    void &myCJpsMixerChannel.inputBufferAdapterError(int error_code);
};
```

---

I tried several things as you can see but it will not compile, the errors are:

InputPoolBufferAdapter.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void InputPoolBufferAdapter::returnDataBufferToPool(ChannelBuffer_t)’:
InputPoolBufferAdapter.cpp:33:50: error: expected initializer before ‘->’ token
InputPoolBufferAdapter.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void InputPoolBufferAdapter::notifyDataAvailable()’:
InputPoolBufferAdapter.cpp:38:32: error: expected initializer before ‘.’ token
InputPoolBufferAdapter.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void InputPoolBufferAdapter::bufferAdapterError(int)’:
InputPoolBufferAdapter.cpp:43:32: error: expected initializer before ‘.’ token

I am at a loss, any more ideas for this no longer 'confounded' but definitely 'befuddled' software guy (I can't believe after 25 years in 'C' embedded systems this has got me so screwed up!).

Thanks all

Comment: Can you post all of your code? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, need to see the code. But pointers rather than references might be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should post some code.
Anyway, without using any C++11 syntax, this is the way I would go:

```
CJ::CJ() : BA(*this) { //CJ constructor here }

BA::BA(const CJ& myCJ) : myCJref(myCJ) { //BA constructor here }
```

Here i only wrote CJ and BA constructors. BA must have a data member
    const CJ& myCJref
for this to work.

Comment: As an aside, please note that you can only initialize references in the initializer list (that is, after the ':' and before the '{' in the constructor), in the way I did

Answer (score 2):

I need to guess a bit, but your class `BA` also has a member variable called `myCJRef`, right? Its type is `const CJ&`, just like the parameter. In that case, you need to do this:

```
BA::BA( const CJ& r ) : myCJRef( r )
{
  // note: myCJRef = r; would not work here.
}
```

because you need to initialize the member variable. The error does not refer to the parameter of your ctor.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably `BA` has a non-static member `const CJ& myCJRef`. A reference type object cannot be left uninitialized, so you need to make sure this reference is initialized by the constructor's member initialization list. So the definition of the constructor will look like so:

```
BA::BA(const CJ& myCJRef)
  : myCJRef(myCJRef)
{
  // ...
}
```

Everything after the `:` is the member initialization list. In this case, it says initialize the member `myCJRef` with the argument `myCJRef` (it's okay that they have the same name).

Comment: Dan and sftrabbit were on the money for me, it looked like Blue was doing basically the same thing. I need to save the (ahem) pointer/reference off and needed to initialize that constructor also. The question that confuses me is that when you initialize the const doesn't it make it incapable of accepting the new value(????) Thanks guys... I need to change my username...